# Is there any way to connect my phone camera feed to ROS?

Tags: android, ros

Currently, I have made an android application that allows me to access my video feed. However, I wish to know if there is a way to directly convert my phone camera feed into a ROS topic to which I could subscribe to directly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us more about your setup?  Do you have ROS running on a PC and want to send your phone camera to that?  Are your phone and your ROS device on the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language is your android application in? For mobile devices, the best ros library is probably the [roslibjs javascript library](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs). There are demo examples [publishing video & imu msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/Publishing%20video%20and%20IMU%20data%20with%20roslibjs) and demoing [basic functionality](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) on how to use it, chiefly in some sort of browser / webapp or js engine. To understand what it's doing, in order to connect to it, reading the [core ROS object constructor / initializer](http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/roslibjs/current/core_Ros.js.html) shows you which transportOptions it supports, and other initialization features (like options.url for your target url). If you chiefly use another language, or you want to send it over the internet, whether as a local buffer or as a remote buffer, you can use the url to transmit your messages.

Otherwise, if you can use python or (more strongly encouraged) C++, those are robust. If it's java... there's some [vague end of life support for kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava) (click kinetic!), but no guarentees. If you want to or are using ROS2, [the official ROS2-java org/repo](https://github.com/ros2-java/ros2_java) is the only thing available (for java &/or android). As it's still being developed, ecosystem java/android support is the depth of this project's implementation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. So the language I am using for my android application currently is Java, and I am interested to know if there are any libraries from your knowledge that work with AndroidSDK to publish information like a ROS node. Thank you!

Comment: Like a ros node or as a ros node? For java, like I said in the post above, there's some support for java out there, but that's _all there is..._ except there is also some newer ROS2 support for java/android (edited post to include that). But that's also what-you-see-is-what-you-get. That's the only library. If this answers your question, please accept it, or suggest a better answer.